# Loop through textboxes in html form using php to get a single value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am doing my best to do most of this on my own, but I have reached a point where I am stuck. I have created an html form and using php have it submitting to a MySQL database.

In one section there are radio buttons and textboxes. My issue is that I cannot find out how to get only the value the user entered in the textbox. (there are five textboxes, but only one will have information).

I need the value that the radio buttons output, so I cannot change that.

Here is my HTML code:

```
        <div class="fieldwrapper">
            <input type="radio" name="Unit_Reason_Codes" value="01F">Electrical Component:
            <input id="elecpart" type="text" value="" size="30" name="part[]" class="FormField" placeholder="Part #">
        </div>
        <div class="fieldwrapper">
            <input type="radio" name="Unit_Reason_Codes" value="01H">Air Cond/Heat Pump Component:
            <input id="airpart" type="text" value="" size="30" name="part[]" class="FormField" placeholder="Part #">
        </div>
        <div class="fieldwrapper">
            <input type="radio" name="Unit_Reason_Codes" value="01J">Motor/Blower:
            <input id="motorpart" type="text" value="" size="30" name="part[]" class="FormField" placeholder="Part #">
        </div>
        <div class="fieldwrapper">
            <input type="radio" name="Unit_Reason_Codes" value="01K">Gas Heating Component:
            <input id="gaspart" type="text" value="" size="30" name="part[]" class="FormField" placeholder="Part #">
        </div>
```

I have tried doing foreach loops using php, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Would anybody be able to help me figure out a php solution for this?

Let me know if more information is required!

Edit: My work I have mostly done before this is VB, so bear with me on this.

Here is my loop attempt, no errors, but couldn't get it posted into the sql database (I have several other things already working, so that might not be the issue).

```
foreach ($_POST['part'] as $key=>$value) {
    $part = $value;
```

}

Comment: Can you show your `foreach` attempt(s)? Were you receiving an error?

Comment: 'foreach ($_POST['part'] as $key=>$value) {
    $part = $value
}'

Comment: Okay, and what happens, that seems correct? Is your form submitting `POST` or `GET`?

Comment: Form is POST, but nothing is appearing in the sql.

'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($part)}' that is the value I have for submitting in the query and it is matched in order with column order in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing $part again and again. You need to add a check for blank value. That's it.

```
foreach ($_POST['part'] as $key=>$value) {
if($value!='')
    $part = $value;
}
```